# Google cloud storage client api not working for patch

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I tried updating header of an object by using API explorer (as well as client library) by giving metadata object as header keys and values.

I only received error respond

```
{
error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid argument."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid argument."
 }
}
```

The request is:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/mbi-figure/o/infovilla_paypal.png?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "metadata": {
  "title": "Kyaw"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've run into a bug with PATCH that is being worked on. Fortunately, there's a workaround. Adding a "projection=full" parameter to the URL should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but url parameter could not be added in gapi.client.rpcRequest ? can i get nightly build for testing?

Comment: Since rpcRequest is not working, I use HTTP request. However it still fail. I think gapi library automatically added 'alt=json', which is causing problem.

Comment: rpcRequest works now. It turn out full_control scope require for PATCH request.